# Lambda fuctions in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create a numpy matrix, like [[2*x-1, x**2], [4-x, x]]. But when I am trying to fill my numpy matrix elements with lambda functions (for example, lambda x: 2*x), I have an error that elements should be string or number. Also, when I am trying to make elements string, they are being cutted. For example, I write x**2, it applies just 'x'

Here is my code

```
matrix_A = np.chararray((n, m))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            current_f = text_var_A[i][j].get()
            matrix_A[i][j] = current_f
```

I am also using tkinter

Comment: `chararray` produces `bytes`, most of your lambdas will fail. `2x` won't work, you want `2*x`

Comment: What's the purpose of this array?  Why not just a list of these functions?  It'll be easier to make, and just as easy to use.

Comment: Yes, it was better to use just an array. Thank you